# $P:X\times Y \rightarrow X$ defined by $P(x,y)=x$ the metric. Prove that $P$ is continuous in $X\times Y$.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $P:X\times Y \rightarrow X$ defined by $P(x,y)=x$, with the metric $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2}$. Prove that $P$ is continuous in $X \times Y$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ then $d_X(x_1,x_2)$...I have no idea how to relate that $d_X(x_1,x_2) \leq \sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2}$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $P$ is continuous at $(x_1,y_1)$ you have to show that given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $d((x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)) <\delta$ implies $d_X(x_1,x_2) <\epsilon$. Take $\delta =\epsilon$ and use the inequality you have written.